# What is the Julia equivalent to classes and instance variables in Java?

Tags: class, struct, julia, instance-variables, multiple-dispatch

I am trying to avoid repeatedly passing a struct in my functions in order to access its fields. In Java this can be avoided by using a class and defining instance variables. What's the equivalent in Julia?

Here is some sample code where I am currently writing functions in the style of `f`, which requires me to pass the struct Param, but ideally I would like to write them in the style of `g` so that I don't need to pass the struct. It seems like a redundant way of writing things, especially if I have multiple functions that need access to the fields and values in Param.

```
struct Param 
    foo::Int
    bar::Bool
end

f(n::Int, param::Param) = n + param.foo
g(n::Int) = n + foo
```

Is it accepted practice to perhaps include the function within the body of the struct?

Comment: If I understand the concepts in Java correctly, the closest you get to a class in Julia is composite type/struct, and instance variables are similar to the fields of a struct, ie. `foo` and `bar` in your struct `Param`. Your function `f` seems to have the right approach. Perhaps you can explain why you find it unsatisfactory?

Comment: @DNF It seems like a redundant and unclean way of writing code when I end up writing multiple functions that require use of the values in the struct.

Comment: https://github.com/Suzhou-Tongyuan/ObjectOriented.jl

Comment: Comment to the update: The correct and idiomatic way is to do as in function `f`. In order to operate on an object, you should pass it to the function that is to operate on it. It is not redundant, but correct and good practice. Perhaps there is some more context?

Comment: I advise against using packages like ObjectOriented.jl. If you must use OOP concepts, a different language will be more suitable.

Comment: I mention [ObjectOriented.jl](https://github.com/Suzhou-Tongyuan/ObjectOriented.jl)  because it directs you to https://suzhou-tongyuan.github.io/ObjectOriented.jl/dev/how-to-translate-oop-into-julia/ which is the documentation that explains how to transfer from OOP to julia. After reading that you may not want to do OOP in julia.

Comment: I think the problem here is trying to do something the Julia language is not supposed to do, so I recommend to try to change your mindset when using Julia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `f` is considered idiomatic in Julia and in most functional programing languages. However, there are a couple patterns to be aware of that you might find useful in some situations.

First, there is [syntax sugar for unpacking the properties of a struct](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-argument-destructuring) in the argument of a function, like this:

```
struct A
    x::Int
    y::String
end

f((; x)::A, b) = x + b
```

```
julia> a = A(1, "hello");

julia> f(a, 2)
3
```

You can also use a similar syntax inside a function to unpack the properties of a struct:

```
function g(a::A, b)
    (; x, y) = a
    length(y) + x + b
end
```

```
julia> g(a, 2)
8
```

Second, in some situations it might make sense to use closures to capture the value of a struct. Here is a toy example of how you can do that:

```
function make_foo_bar(a::A)
    (; x, y) = a
    func1(b) = x + b
    func2(b) = length(y) + x + b
    func1, func2
end
```

```
julia> foo, bar = make_foo_bar(a)
(var"#func1#7"{Int64}(1), var"#func2#8"{String, Int64}("hello", 1))

julia> foo(2)
3

julia> bar(2)
8
```

Inside `make_foo_bar`, I've named the functions `func1` and `func2` to emphasize that the names of the functions inside `make_foo_bar` can be different from the names of the variables to which you assign the output functions. In this example, `foo` and `bar` are variables to which two different anonymous functions are assigned.